# RabbitMQ - Avoiding duplicate messages at publisher side

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am using RabbitMQ to send notifications to the user. The user can read his queue at any time.

The problem I am facing is that the queue is filled with lots of notifications during the night, and when the user returns in the morning, he has to process these messages sequentially. A lot of these notifications are even duplicates.

I guess it would make sense to improve this at the publisher side. That is, before adding a new notification, we investigate if there are already pending notifications in the queue. If this is the case, we only queue a new notification if it is really a new notification, hence avoiding duplicates.

We might even go further and extend this by combining notifications: instead of simply queuing a new notification, we could replace the present notifications from the queue by a new one which holds the sum of these notifications and the new one (for example in an array of inner notifications).

Is this possible with AMQP/RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by default you can't replace an existing message.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. But what could we do to solve/improve my scenario? Basically, I am trying to solve scenario's in which queues are 'overloaded', because the consumer has not been reading for a while (which for example happens during night, when the consumer is offline). I want to avoid that the consumer has to handle each message, without knowledge that these messages are duplicates of messages further in the queue.

Comment: you could use the `TTL` extension and remove the messages older than X seconds https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html 

The messages duplication are from application side! if you want to avoid them you have to trace the messages are you sending.

Answer (score 6):

This [rabbitmq plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication) has been written to tackle your issue.

You can enable de-duplication on a queue via setting its `x-message-deduplication` argument to `true`.

Then, your publishers will need to provide the `x-deduplication-header` message header with a value meaningful for de-duplication. The value could be a unique message `ID` or the `MD5`/`SHA1` hash of the body for example.

Comment: Hello, I downloaded the plugin and the related ez files. Did the changes with the header and the queue argument and then tried to enable the plugin. Here is the error I got:

** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {:plugin_built_with_incompatible_erlang, 'rabbitmq_message_deduplication'}
{:case_clause, {:plugin_built_with_incompatible_erlang, 'rabbitmq_message_deduplication'}}

rabbitmq server version is 3.8.7. Do I need to upgrade?